# How to take the name and extension of a file from a reworked URL?

Tags: php, curl, url, redirect

**Let's take an example:** `https://example.com/fileDocx` , refers to this file `https://example.com/fileDocx.docx` . Now, I would like to know how to get the name of this file and the extension from the reworked URL which does not contain any information belonging to the file? I know I have to use the cURL function but I can't do it?
Can you help me to do it please?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am not sure you understood how such URLs work ... The short answer to your actual question is: "you can't" / "you don't". You are right, the information is not there. _Typically_ such "pretty URLs" (or whatever you want to call them) are defined along a naming scheme, so that the name / path of the actual resource can be derived from the requested URL. An alternative would be to test whether some potentially matching resource for a requested URL exists, this is typically called "content negotiation", but that is time consuming, less efficient.

Comment: OK, for the sake of completeness: there also is the concept of a document management system: all resources are managed inside a database which offers the connection between a registered and requested URL and the internal resource that has been registered for it.

Comment: @chris-haas No. I don't know what to do. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the `Location` HTTP header when a 301 or 302 redirect happens? Or possibly the `Content-disposition` header? Or when you click the first link you get a page that says “Your download will start in 5 seconds…” and you want that? You are going to have to be more specific with your question, a “reworked URL” is unfortunately too vague.